# ConnectionString for production Windows Form

Tags: winforms, entity-framework

Let's say that i would like to release for production a Windows Forms application. I would like data in it to be password protected, the app uses a local db to save data:

```
 <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Marco\Documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\ProjectName\ProjectName\db\aspnet-dbname-20180717114015.mdf;User Id=Username;Password=examplepassword;Initial Catalog=aspnet-dbname-20180717114015;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

1. What type of connectionstring should i set?
2. Should i also ask users to install sql server? or this is self managed from the framework?

Comment: Yes, LocalDb needs an installation of SQL Server. And what do you mean by "data in it to be password protected"? What do you want to accomplish or prevent, exactly?

Comment: Hey Thank you, I would like to set a password for db, in order to avoid people to access it without knowing the password. 
How can i ensure that user has sql server installed?

Comment: You can't do that. If you're going to install a SQL Server on a user's machine and give your app access to it, so can the user.

Comment: Nice, what could be a workaround in your opinion?

Comment: Password protection is authentication. That's not related to connection strings or sql server installation. Your question is unclear and not well-defined.